# Loss functions for regression

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, machine-learning, bayesian

[From PRML Bishop, p:46]

The average or expected loss function is given by
$$E[L] = \int\int (y(x)-t)^2 p(x,t)\ \ dx\ \ dt$$,

where, the loss function  $L = (y(x)-t)^2$, given x and the corresponding output t .

To obtain the $y(x)$ which minimizes the expected loss,  $\frac {\partial E[L]}  {\partial  y(x)}$ is calculated and set to $0$. Which is the following:

$$\frac {\partial E[L]}  {\partial  y(x)}=2\int\{y(x)-t\}p(x,t)dt$$

I am facing difficulty in doing this differentiation myself. Could anyone help?

Very Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is inconvenient to use the same variable $x$ as a parameter and as a integration variable. When taking the variation $\frac{\delta E[L]}{\delta y(x)}$, we should write $E$ as

$$E[L] = \iint (y(x')-t)^2p(x',t)dx'dt$$

To compute this, we start with the rule

$$\frac{\delta y(x')}{\delta y(x)}=\delta(x-x')$$

where $\delta$ is the delta-function. Since variation acts just like a normal differentiation, we have

$$\frac{\delta [(y(x')-t)^2p]}{\delta y(x)}=2(y(x')-t)p(x',t)\frac{\delta y(x')}{\delta y(x)} = 2(y(x')-t)p(x',t)\delta(x-x')$$

where we used the chain-rule. The delta function (distribution) acts under a integral as $\int \delta(x-x')g(x')dx' = g(x)$ and this gives us

$$\frac{\delta E }{\delta y(x)} = \iint \frac{\delta[(y(x')-t)^2p(x',t)]}{\delta y(x)}dx'dt \\= \iint 2(y(x')-t)p(x',t) \delta(x-x')dx'dt = 2\int(y(x)-t)p(x,t) dt$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, i have a doubt. I would be grateful if you could clarify that. Here, y(x) is the predicted value for x . And in the training data expected input-output pairs <x,t> are give. Both x and y(x) are real-valued. So, i am not sure why we need x' in the computation?

Comment: @arindammitra You are interested in finding the function $y(x)$ which minimizes the loss function $E[L]$ ($E$ is a functional - it taken in a function and outputs a number) that where $x$ enters the picture.

Comment: You have used x and x' both , so i was little confused.

Comment: @Winther I am confused about the second equation. Would you mind giving some more clarifications? Thanks!

Comment: @danche See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative_of_a_function